# pragma disable for noUnusedLocals?

Tags: typescript

I've turned on `noUnusedLocals` but I have a function that just checks for the existence of the first element but doesn't use it. Is there a pragma to turn this warning off for a code block?

Example:

```
export function has<T>(sequence: Iterable<T>): boolean {
    for (let element of sequence) {
        element; // Needed to quiet compiler setting `noUnusedLocals`.
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The docs say to use `_`:

> Parameters declaration with names starting with _ are exempt from the unused
>   parameter checking.

(See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#flag-unused-declarations-with---nounusedparameters-and---nounusedlocals))

But that only seems to apply for **parameters**, not local variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer in the strictest sense but `_` as a name or name prefix suppresses `--noUnusedLocals` in `for..of` loop declarators in TypeScript 2.2.2 which is the current release at the time of this writing.